# VPN blocking wifi connection

Tags: wireless, 22.04, internet, vpn

I was running a VPN (Cyberghost) in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and I turn off my computer without deactivating the VPN. When I turn on my computer cannot connect to internet, Wifi is working and recognizing the net but there is not connection to internet. Help and thank you